# Extract substring from string which includes special charaters

Tags: java, regex

What is the best way to extract `"year=2017"` and `"taxType=RE"` from the below given string?

```
href="/property/33951?year=2017&taxType=RE"
```

Comment: are you looking for the solution of this particular string or string following this pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can use this regex [**`(?i)year=(\d{4}?)&taxType=(\[a-z\]+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/CT5cZu/1), which can match two groups one is one or more degits after `year=` the second one is one or more alphabitics after `&taxType=` :

**Java demo**

```
String str = "/property/33951?year=2017&taxType=RE";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)year=(\\d+?)&taxType=([A-Z]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Year = " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("taxType = " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

**Output**

```
Year = 2017
taxType = RE
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt solution i appreciate. it indeed did the trick .

Answer (score 0):

This `(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)` is what I use to get `GET` parameters usually.
You need to look for Group 2 to get the param and Group 3 to get the value.

**As requested in comments**

```
String str = "/property/33951?year=2017&taxType=RE";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\?|\\&)([^=]+)=([^&]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2) + " = " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: great explanation.  please provide a code sample, in order to be a "good answer"

Answer (score 0):

for android development:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("/property/33951?year=2017&taxType=RE");
    String year = uri.getQueryParameter("year");
    String taxType= uri.getQueryParameter("taxType");
```

Comment: What is `Uri` class? Standard Java doesn't seem to have it. Did you perhaps mean `android.net.Uri`? If yes you should mention it since question is not tagged as `android` related.